# content extends outside its td border - html table problem

Tags: html, css

I want to preface this by saying that I'm fairly new to css.

My current problem is that the content inside my td is extending outside of the td. Here's my html:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="example incorrect height style.css">
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="container">
                        <p><b>Content</b></p>
                        <p>Content Content Content Content</p>
                        <p>
                            Content: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="container">
                        <p><b>Content</b></p>
                        <p>Content Content Content Content</p>
                        <p>
                            Content: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here's my css:

```
.container {
    border-radius: 25px;
    background: lightblue;
    padding: 5%; 
    width: 80%;
    height: 80%;
    max-height: 80%;
    
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
    table-layout:fixed;
}

table, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

td {
    height: 200px;
}
```

The width of each container looks correct, however the height is very off. It's extending out of the td at max-height: 80%. Why is that?

Also I noticed that using a % for padding doesn't work well. It seems like the % uses the viewport size rather than the width and height of either container or td. Why is that? (Try setting it to 50% to see what I mean)

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the padding with percentage value.
You might wanna use the specific value for padding
ex.

```
.container {
    border-radius: 25px;
    background: lightblue;
    padding: 10px; 
    width: 80%;
    height: 80%;
    max-height: 80%;
}
```

Comment: The <td> tag doesn't have specific width. it might be the reason why the padding with percentage value does not work accurately.
though I am not 100% sure

Comment: And if you want to add padding, just add the padding in td not in container (if you are referring to your background color)

Comment: I just googled it and apparently height doesn't include padding, which explains it. Setting box-sizing: border-box; and margins to px rather than % solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Add overflow and padding to td like this

```
Td  {
Overflow: hidden;
Padding: 4px 6px;
}
```